# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Подскажите где ошибка, почему не могу запустить?

```
(untitled) E:\Work\python\djangocrm>python manage.py runserver 8008


Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 399, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\Work\python\djangocrm\djangocrm\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog.urls'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 598, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 583, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 301, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 307, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 347, in tick
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 363, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 262, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 103, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Users\Egor\untitled\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 139, in iter_modules_and_files
    if not path.exists():
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1314, in exists
    self.stat()
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 1136, in stat
    return self._accessor.stat(self)
  File "C:\Users\Egor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
OSError: [WinError 123] Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Это settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'blog',
]
```

Это urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Это blog/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

Это blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def home(request):
    return render(request, "partial/home.html")
```

Comment: попробуйде в INSTALLED_APPS указать 'blog.apps.PollsConfig'

Answer (score 0):

В файле urls.py (который НЕ blog/urls.py) в строке `path('', include('blog.urls'))` вы пытаетесь сделать переход на домашнюю страницу сайта, я рекомендую вам попробовать обойтись без include(), т.к. это весьма плохая практика, которая приводит к некорректной работе приложения. Просто сделайте так: `path('здесь можете либо оставить пустые кавычки, либо вписать свой url', ваша_функция)` импортируйте вьюху из этой же директории и сделайте роутинг через неё.

Answer (score 0):

Проверь есть ли у тебя файл `__init__.py` в папке blog. Настоятельно советую следовать оф. документации при первом знакомстве с django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/